# Regular Expression to replace arithmetic operators in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of string that contains arithmetic operators and I would like to replace those arithmetic operators in the array with a new arithmetic operator.

For instance:

```
var equation = '5.0 + 9.34 - 6.0 * 2.1 * 3.1 / 2.0';

var newEquation = equation.replace(/+-*//, '+');
```

However, it does not change to the wanted result. Please advise. Your contribution is much appreciated.

Comment: That's not an array. It's just a string literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [character class(`[]`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```js
var equation = '5.0 + 9.34 - 6.0 * 2.1 * 3.1 / 2.0';

var newEquation = equation.replace(/[+*\/-]/g, '+');
// or : equation.replace(/[+\-*/]/g, '+');

console.log(newEquation);
```

---

**UPDATE :** For avoiding negative numbers use [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```js
var equation = '-5.0 + 9.34 - 6.0 * -2.1 * 3.1 / -2.0';

var newEquation = equation.replace(/(?!^-)[+*\/-](\s?-)?/g, '+$1');

console.log(newEquation);
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/kJ4iA4/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution @Pranav Is there a way to differentiate from a negative number? For instance: '-5.0 + 9.34 - -6.0'

Comment: Thank you @Pranav. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Clay : glad to help :)